# How to yup validate with single react select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup

i have a required select menu that is created using single value react select.
if user doesnt select any option from select menu and clicks save button i want to display error.

below is my code,

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    [DESCRIPTION_KEY]: Yup.string(),
    [NAME_KEY]: Yup.string()
        .max(256, 'The name should not be longer than 256 characters')
        .required('Please fill out this field.'),
});

const options = [
    { value: 'option1', label: 'option1' },
    { value: 'option2', label: 'option2' },
    { value: 'option3', label: 'option3'},
];
const Parent= ({ formikBag }: { formikBag: FormikProps}) => {
    const handleSave = () => {
        const promiseArr = formFields.map(field =>
            validationSchema.validateAt(field, values!).catch(e => e)
        );
        const validationsArr = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
        const errorsArr = validationsArr.filter(
            field => field instanceof ValidationError
        );

        if (!isEmpty(errorsArr)) {
            errorsArr.forEach(fieldError => {
                setFieldTouched && setFieldTouched(fieldError.path, true, true);
            });
            return;
        }
        return (
            <>
                <FormField
                    label="Name" 
                    fieldId={NAME_KEY}
                    required
                 />
                 <FormField
                     as="textarea"
                     label="Description"
                     fieldId={DESCRIPTION_KEY}
                 />
                 <FormField label="single value select menu *" fieldId= 
                     {SINGLE_SELECT}>
                     <Select //uses react select
                         id={field.name}
                         inputId={field.name}
                         onChange={(option: SelectOption) =>
                             form.setFieldValue(field.name, option.value)
                         }
                         options={options}
                         placeholder="Select single option"
                         value={options.filter(option => option.value === 
                             field.value)}
                         />
                     )}
                 </FormField>
                 <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
             </>
         );
     }
```

I am not sure how to do validation for react select single value. could someone help me with this. thanks. i am new to using react and yup validation.

**EDIT**
below is what i have tried

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    [DESCRIPTION_KEY]: Yup.string(),
    [NAME_KEY]: Yup.string()
        .max(256, 'The name should not be longer than 256 characters')
        .required('Please fill out this field.'),
    [SINGLE_SELECT]: Yup.string()
        .required('Please selection an option');
});
```

but this doesnt work.